# Facebook android sdk login button without fragments

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am working in Android Studio in a project that does not have any fragments. I keep getting a NullPointerException on loginButton even after assigning it with the line:

```
            loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
```

The relevant part of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
    }
```

And activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">        

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I cannot figure out why loginbutton would still be null after that line and I am not sure how to fix this. If anyone could help me get a project set up with a Facebook login that works with Android Studio, that would be great even if it uses fragments. I have nothing against fragments, but I am new to Android so I decided not to use fragments because I do not fully understand them. I looked through Facebook's example projects, but I could not find a Android Studio project file and kept failing to set up a Project with their individual sample files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the *setContentView()* to any place before assign *loginButton*. Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //right here
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the following code it works for me, while using Facebook SDK 4.7

[facebook login android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33584208/3959610)

Answer (score 1):

Your views (login button) must be initialized after  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` So you need to move

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
});
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

**NOTE:** `FB SDK` should init  before `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

This will give a null pointer error.
So all you need to do is Initialize the facebookSDK first, then setContentView and then set the callBackManager.

Comment: is this solution complete?

Comment: yes. Even I was having the same error on some other sdk.