# how to implement facebook login in android using facebook sdk 4.7

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to login with facebook using android sdk 4.7.
I have tried the following link
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-facebook-integration-tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: The best example for facebook login : http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook_108

Answer (score 16):

This code works for me, try it out and check that you are using facebook sdk 4.7

```
package com.kushal.facebooklogin;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.facebook.*;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
    import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

    public class FacebookLogin extends FragmentActivity
    {
        private TextView tvfirst_name, tvlast_namee, tvfull_name, tvEmail;
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;
        LoginButton login_button;
        String email,name,first_name,last_name;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            tvfirst_name        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
            tvlast_namee        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
            tvfull_name         = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.full_name);
            tvEmail             = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
            login_button        = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

            login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));
            login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
                {
                    login_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    GraphRequest graphRequest   =   GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
                        {
                            Log.d("JSON", ""+response.getJSONObject().toString());

                            try
                            {
                                email       =   object.getString("email");
                                name        =   object.getString("name");
                                first_name  =   object.optString("first_name");
                                last_name   =   object.optString("last_name");

                                tvEmail.setText(email);
                                tvfirst_name.setText(first_name);
                                tvlast_namee.setText(last_name);
                                tvfull_name.setText(name);
                                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,email");
                    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
                    graphRequest.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception)
                {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

the xml design is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/full_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the mainefest file is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kushal.facebooklogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FacebookLogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: To get the profile picture: `"http://graph.facebook.com/" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "/picture?type=large";`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). Here you have explained in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) how to build a Facebook Login to your app.

It says:

> The simplest way to add Facebook Login to your app is to add
>   `LoginButton` from the SDK. This is a custom view implementation of a
>   `Button`. You can use this button in your app to implement Facebook
>   Login.
>   [image]
>
> **Add the Login Button**
>
> Add the button to your layout XML file with the full class name,
>   com.facebook.widget.LoginButton:
>
> ```
> <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
>     android:id="@+id/login_button"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
> ```
>
> Then set up the button in your UI by adding it to a fragment and
>   update your activity to use your fragment.
>
> You can customize the properties of Login button and register a
>   callback in your `onCreateView()` method.
>
> Properties you can customize includes `LoginBehavior`, `DefaultAudience`,
>   `ToolTipPopup`.Style and permissions on the `LoginButton`. For example:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(
>         LayoutInflater inflater,
>         ViewGroup container,
>         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);
>
>     loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
>     loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
>     // If using in a fragment
>     loginButton.setFragment(this);    
>     // Other app specific specialization
>
>     // Callback registration
>     loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
>             // App code
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onCancel() {
>             // App code
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
>             // App code
>         }
>     });    
> }
> ```
>
> If you use the `LoginButton` in a fragment, you need to set the fragment
>   on the button as shown by calling `setFragment`.
>
> You then need to call `FacebookSdk.initialize` to initialize the SDK,
>   and then call `CallbackManager.Factory.create` to create a callback
>   manager to handle login responses. Here's an example of adding the
>   callback in a fragment:
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
>     CallbackManager callbackManager;
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
>         callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
>         LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.usersettings_fragment_login_button);
>         loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { ... });
>     }
> ```
>
> Finally you should call `callbackManager.onActivityResult` to pass the
>   login results to the `LoginManager` via `callbackManager`.
>
> **Register a Callback**
>
> To respond to a login result, you need to register a callback with
>   either `LoginManager` or `LoginButton`. If you register the callback with
>   `LoginButton`, don't need to register the callback on Login manager.
>
> You add the callback to your activity or fragment's `onCreate()` method:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
>
>     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
>
>     LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
>             new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
>                     // App code
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCancel() {
>                      // App code
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
>                      // App code   
>                 }
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> If login succeeds, the `LoginResult` parameter has the new `AccessToken`,
>   and the most recently granted or declined permissions.
>
> You don't need a `registerCallback` for login to succeed, you can choose
>   to follow current access token changes with the `AccessTokenTracker`
>   class described below.
>
> Then in `onActivityResult()` forward the login results to the
>   `callbackManager` created in `onCreate()`:
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
> }
> ```
>
> Every activity and fragment that you integrate with the FacebookSDK
>   Login or Share should forward `onActivityResult` to the `callbackManager`.
>
> To learn more about getting additional permissions see:
>
> [Managing Permissions, Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions),
>   [Permissions with Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5)

Comment: I have not yet try Android SDK. I mean which version u use?

Answer (score 1):

I have used facebook sdk **4.10.0** to integrate login in my android app.
Tutorial I followed is :

***[Facebook login integration android studio.](https://demonuts.com/facebook-integration-in-android/)***

You will be able to get first name, last name, email, gender , facebook id and birth date from facebbok.

Above tutorial also explains how to create app in facebook developer console through video.

Gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demonuts.fblogin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.androidquery:androidquery:0.26.9'
}
```

Source code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.demonuts.fblogin.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivpic"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/btnfb"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />   </LinearLayout>
```

Code for MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



      private AQuery aQuery;
        private ImageView ivpic;
        private TextView tvdetails;
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;
        private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
        private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
        private LoginButton loginButton;
        private FacebookCallback&lt;LoginResult&gt; callback = new FacebookCallback&lt;LoginResult&gt;() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                // Application code
                                try {
                                    Log.d("tttttt",object.getString("id"));
                                    String birthday="";
                                    if(object.has("birthday")){
                                        birthday = object.getString("birthday"); // 01/31/1980 format
                                    }

                                    String fnm = object.getString("first_name");
                                    String lnm = object.getString("last_name");
                                    String mail = object.getString("email");
                                    String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                    String fid = object.getString("id");
                                    tvdetails.setText("Name: "+fnm+" "+lnm+" \n"+"Email: "+mail+" \n"+"Gender: "+gender+" \n"+"ID: "+fid+" \n"+"Birth Date: "+birthday);
                                    aQuery.id(ivpic).image("https://graph.facebook.com/" + fid + "/picture?type=large");
                                    //https://graph.facebook.com/143990709444026/picture?type=large
                                    Log.d("aswwww","https://graph.facebook.com/"+fid+"/picture?type=large");

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, birthday, location");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tvdetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            ivpic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivpic);

            loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnfb);
            aQuery = new AQuery(this);

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };

            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {

                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
            profileTracker.stopTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this simple facebook login Library:

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Here is the link to my uploaded demo for simple facebook login with custom button: http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook_108

Its the simplest way to implement the facebook login in android application.

You can add the button like this :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnFb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

And in gradle File you can add:

```
compile 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.1.1'
```

Please check.

Comment: This is Deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

```
FACEBOOK LOGIN STEPBYSTEP 

   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        printHashKey();

meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />



btnFacebook.setReadPermissions("public_profile","email");


 btnFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            String facebook_email;
            String name;
            String profilePicUrl;
            private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("facabook","Step1");
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.e("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                // Application code
                                try {
                                    facebook_email = object.getString("email");
                                    name=object.getString("name");
                                    if (object.has("picture")) {
                                        profilePicUrl = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                        // set profile image to imageview using Picasso or Native methods
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                        @Override
                                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                                            // profile2 is the new profile
                                            Log.e("facebook - profile", profile2.getFirstName());

                                            facebookLogin(facebook_email,name,profilePicUrl,Constant.DUMMY_PASSWORD);
                                            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                        }
                                    };
                                    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                                } else {
                                    facebookLogin(facebook_email,name,profilePicUrl,Constant.DUMMY_PASSWORD);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.type(large)");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e("facebook - onCancel", "cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("facebook - onError", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e("Request Code", requestCode + "===========");
        if(requestCode==64206)
        {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```